# How to disable multi-part sftp upload using the FileZilla client

Tags: filezilla

Is there someway that I can disable the multi-part upload through SFTP using FileZilla client.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "multi-part upload"?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl FileZilla tries to upload files in pieces, I would like it to cache everything first and then upload everything in one go, all bytes thrown in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

That's how SFTP protocol works.

The SFTP client writes a file in chunks.

While you may theoretically upload ta he file using a single write operation, the [SFTP specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13) does not recommend sizes over 32 KB:

> The maximum size of a packet is in practice determined by the client (the maximum size of read or write requests that it sends, plus a few bytes of packet overhead).  All servers SHOULD support packets of at least 34000 bytes (where the packet size refers to the full length, including the header above).  This should allow for reads and writes of at most 32768 bytes.

In any case, there's no way you can tweak this in FileZilla. It always writes by 16 KB.